# Opening list of URLs in sheet/DF and saving the new URL back to sheet / DF

Tags: python, pandas, url

I have a sheet stored as a pandas dataframe with a column of URLs (e.g. one URL per row / cell) that have an embedded link within that URL (e.g. think Bitly URLs that direct to some website).

What I want to do is write a function that will open every URL in the column e.g. (bitly.com/example) and then save the new URL that is embedded within that url e.g. "www.bitly.com?utm_source=example-source&utm_medium=example-medium&utm_campaign=example-campaign-name" into a new column within the dataframe.

Is there a quick and easy package to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `requests`: `[requests.get(url).url for url in df['url_col']]`

Comment: amazing thank you!!

Comment: No problem, good luck.